# Android Google Map v2 Not rendering

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

So I have searched the internet without success and have followed countless tutorials, yet I still cant get my application to render a map.  At best, I can get it to display a screen with the zoom toggles, but no map and I get a "Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices" error.  I have checked and rechecked my api key and it is correct.

My Activity code.  It is fair to note that nothing is happening here because I have commented out the fragment manager that gets the map.  If I uncomment this, it crashes with a null pointer exception.

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity { 
private GoogleMap myMap;
private LatLng Location;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    Location = new LatLng(0,0);
   // MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

     //  myMap = fragment.getMap();

  }


}
```

My xml for it

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
 />
```

My Manifest File

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.Map.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission android:name="com.Map.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.Map.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.Map.android.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.Map.android.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.Map.android.MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.Map.android.Info"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_info" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.Map.android.InfoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_info" >
    </activity>
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
   android:value="MYKEY"/>
    </application>

 </manifest>
```

I understand this has been a question asked many times before, but I cannot seem to find someone else's answer that fixes my problem.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What device and Android version is the app crashing on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using supportmapfragment class as defined in your xml, then

Add this  `import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;`

and change your map intialisation line as:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
```